# How to find the oldest person in People Array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying retrieve the oldest person from the array using the .reduce() method in javascript. The array is below. What I'm struggling with is writing the correct syntax for the .reduce method to accomplish this. The code I'm using is below and I keep getting the result 'undefined'. I've been working with the code for a little while and feel I might be making a simple mistake but a nudge in the right direction would be helpful!

```
let findTheOldest = function(people) {
  let total = 0
     people.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    if ((curr.yearOfDeath - curr.yearOfBirth) > total) {
    total = (curr.yearOfDeath - curr.yearOfBirth);
    }
    return prev;
  }, 0);
}
console.log(findTheOldest(people));
```

```
const people = [
      {
        name: 'Carly',
        yearOfBirth: 1942,
        yearOfDeath: 1970,
      },
      {
        name: 'Ray',
        yearOfBirth: 1962,
        yearOfDeath: 2011
      },
      {
        name: 'Jane',
        yearOfBirth: 1912,
        yearOfDeath: 1941
      },
    ]
```

Comment: Note that the first argument in reduce is not the previous value but accumulator. The accumulator accumulates callback's return values.

Comment: Are you dead-set on using reduce?

Comment: Hi Joel, if you have anything better in mind, please share. I have shared an answer which does not use reduce. You never know what new thing you can learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined because the function findTheOldest just return nothing.
If you want to keep your function and using your variable total (not very optimised) you need to return the oldestPerson like this:

```
let findTheOldest = function(people) {
  let total = 0
  let OldestPerson = {}
  people.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    if ((curr.yearOfDeath - curr.yearOfBirth) > total) {
      total = (curr.yearOfDeath - curr.yearOfBirth);
      OldestPerson = curr
    }
    return prev;
  })
  return OldestPerson
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a comparator to sort the whole array in the order you want as well and get the first element.  Ironically, the example provided in this link is almost the same as we have here :
http://www.mattmorgante.com/technology/javascript-sort-compare

Does not use reduce but thought this was interesting.

```js
    const people = [{
        name: 'Carly',
        yearOfBirth: 1942,
        yearOfDeath: 1970,
      },
      {
        name: 'Ray',
        yearOfBirth: 1962,
        yearOfDeath: 2011
      },
      {
        name: 'Jane',
        yearOfBirth: 1912,
        yearOfDeath: 1941
      },
    ]
    const oldestPeople = people.sort(function(a,b) {
  const lastPerson = a.yearOfDeath - a.yearOfBirth;
  const nextPerson = b.yearOfDeath - b.yearOfBirth;
  if (lastPerson > nextPerson) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
});

console.log(people[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

For `reduce` to work, you'd have to either re-calculate the age of the accumulator every time (somewhat inelegant), or save it in an outside variable. Then, return inside the callback depending on whether the accumulator or the current item being iterated over has the greater age:

```js
const getAge = ({ yearOfBirth, yearOfDeath }) => yearOfDeath - yearOfBirth;
const findTheOldest = function(people) {
  let accumAge = getAge(people[0]);
  return people.reduce((accum, curr) => {
    const currAge = getAge(curr);
    if (currAge > accumAge) {
      accumAge = currAge;
      return curr;
    }
    return accum;
  });
}

const people = [{
    name: 'Carly',
    yearOfBirth: 1942,
    yearOfDeath: 1970,
  },
  {
    name: 'Ray',
    yearOfBirth: 1962,
    yearOfDeath: 2011
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane',
    yearOfBirth: 1912,
    yearOfDeath: 1941
  },
]
console.log(findTheOldest(people));
```

While it's *possible* with `reduce`, I think it would be somewhat ugly and not entirely appropriate

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce. While it is ugly it shortens the code quite a bit =)

```js
const people = [
      {
        name: 'Carly',
        yearOfBirth: 1942,
        yearOfDeath: 1970,
      },
      {
        name: 'Ray',
        yearOfBirth: 1962,
        yearOfDeath: 2011
      },
      {
        name: 'Jane',
        yearOfBirth: 1912,
        yearOfDeath: 1941
      },
    ]

    const res = people.reduce((prevVal,curVal) => {
      return prevVal.yearOfDeath-prevVal.yearOfBirth < curVal.yearOfDeath-curVal.yearOfBirth ? curVal: prevVal;
    })
    console.log(res.name,res.yearOfDeath-res.yearOfBirth);
```